# Content length is not showing in HTTP response header

Tags: http-content-length

Accept-Ranges:bytes

Cache-Control:max-age=1296915

Connection:Keep-Alive

Content-Encoding:gzip

Content-Type:application/pdf

Date:Mon, 27 Jun 2016 07:24:58 GMT

ETag:"9c96c69837a1d11:0-gzip"

Keep-Alive:timeout=15, max=100

Last-Modified:Thu, 28 Apr 2016 10:20:32 GMT

Server:Apache

Transfer-Encoding:chunked

Vary:Accept-Encoding

X-Powered-By:ASP.NET

---

I want to show content length in response header

Answer (score 4):

The content-length header field will not be sent if a Transfer-Encoding header field is present. Basically, the decimal value of the content-length in OCTETs represents both the entity-length and the transfer-length. If there is some transfer-encoding, then these two lengths will be different and consequently the content-length value should be ignored.

Comment: i have a static file .and configured in nginx to send via application/json.what i need to do to show this header in my response?